# Bridge JMS Message to SSE Endpoint in Quarkus

Tags: jms, quarkus, smallrye

In Spring project, I used `Sinks` to emit events into a SSE endpoint, it worked well, check:

https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/blob/master/dgs-subscription-sse/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/DataFetchers.kt#L33

But when I tried to Smallrye Mutiny `MultiEmitterProcessor` to archive the same purpose, it failed.

The example project is https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/tree/master/jms

```java
    MultiEmitterProcessor<Message> emitterProcessor = MultiEmitterProcessor.create();

    void receive() {
        var consumer = jmsContext.createConsumer(helloQueue);
        consumer.setMessageListener(
                msg -> {
                    try {
                        var received = jsonb.fromJson(msg.getBody(String.class), Message.class);
                        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "consuming message: {0}", received);
                        emitterProcessor.emit(received);
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

And in the Resource class,

```java
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    @RestStreamElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Multi<Message> stream() {
        // see: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35220
        return handler.emitterProcessor.toMulti().toHotStream();
    }
```

1. I am not sure `MultiEmitterProcessor` is good to work as a hot stream?
2. or there are something like Reactor `ConnectableFlux` to connect to a hot stream manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I move the following codes from Resource class

```java
emitterProcessor.toMulti()
```

into a method in the handler class, then it works.

```java
public Multi<Message> stream() {
    return processor.toMulti().broadcast().toAllSubscribers();
}
```

Check the final working example: https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/tree/master/jms